# How to return error from share extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

if i close my extension with

```
[self.extensionContext cancelRequestWithError:error];
```

the error **is not returned** to the app via `UIActivityViewController` completion blocks `activityError`

```
[vc setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
    // activityError is nil, even when cancelRequestWithError: called  with error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **userDefaults** Suite with app groups and set a boolean value indicating error if it happened in the **Extension**  / save  it's string description and read it in the app , also don't forget to make it false / nil after process . . .